# What is the use of codes in pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

If you see the definition of pandas MultiIndex in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html there is an argument called 'codes'. There is a function also called set_codes as documented in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_codes.html#pandas.MultiIndex.set_codes . I am unable to understand what is the purpose of these codes in general. Can anyone demonstrate using an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

codes can specify the location of each label.

for example:

```
pd.MultiIndex(levels =  [[1, 2], ['red', 'blue']], codes=[[1,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1]])
```

give the result:

```
MultiIndex([(2,  'red'),
        (1, 'blue'),
        (2,  'red'),
        (1, 'blue')],
       )
```

While if we change the codes:

```
pd.MultiIndex(levels =  [[1, 2], ['red', 'blue']], codes=[[0,1,0,1], [1,0,1,0]])
```

Then the result is:

```
MultiIndex([(1, 'blue'),
        (2,  'red'),
        (1, 'blue'),
        (2,  'red')],
       )
```

Comment: I still don't get it. How do codes [[1,0,1,0], [0,1,0,1]] translate into locations?

Comment: @Hui - you likely solved this but for others, the index location of the first array in codes corresponds to the value of the index level first array, so [ [1, 0, 1, 0] -> first one ] corresponds to the first item [[1, 2] -> this index value] equating to the first column of (2, 1, 2, 1) and the second code [0, 1, 0, 1] corresponds to the 2nd index of ['red', 'blue'] making ('red', 'blue', 'red', blue'), so together [[1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1]] corresponds to (2, 'red'), (1, 'blue'), (2, 'red'), (1, 'blue'). Hopefully that helps.